# Overfull hboxes with section formatting from tex.SE answer

Tags: sectioning, boxes, tabulary

I wanted to incorporate the great looking section formatting from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482982/159388) answer but it gives overfull hboxes for every heading (see [here in overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/rndvzchkwzfh)). I didn't want to abuse the comments under that answer so instead ask it here.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work without any overfull box warnings and end up with a rectangular box that is just as wide as the textwidth.

In comparison to the original, I replaced `\tabcolsep` with `2\fboxsep`. (Since the default value for `\tabcolsep` and `\fboxsep` are 6pt and 3pt, respectively, this should not make any difference, but once you decide to redefine either of them, this will indeed make a difference.) I also substracted `2\fboxrule` instead of just `\fboxrule`, since there is a vertical line on both sides of the table

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper,svgnames, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{array, tabulary}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext, xcolor}
\definecolor{seccolor}{RGB}{41,48,57}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{8pt}}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\sffamily\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}\color{SlateGrey}}
                              {}
                              {0pt}
                              {\fbox{\begin{tabulary}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{@{}l!{\vline width 1.2pt}L}\thesection &#1 \end{tabulary}} }

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{2}
    \section{Section Title. Some more more text to have a really very very long section title.}
    \blindtext
    \section{A much shorter section title}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer. In the document, where I want to use this, I want to use ```\usepackage[headheight=2.6pt, includehead, includefoot, top = 1cm, bottom = 2cm, left = 3cm, right = 4cm]{geometry}```. With this line included, your solution also gives a overfull hbox. Is my usage of the geometry package incorrect?

Comment: If I take the code from my answer and replace `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` with `\usepackage[headheight=2.6pt, includehead, includefoot, top = 1cm, bottom = 2cm, left = 3cm, right = 4cm]{geometry}`, I get a document that still compiles without any warnings or errors. The reason for the overfull box must be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: If I do the same in the above linked overleaf document, I get ```Overfull \hbox (3.67433pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 22--22```.