# Shrinking text in a node, such that the minimum width and minimum height are the actual width and height of the node

Tags: fontsize, nodes, width

I want to shrink the text in a node such that the minimum height and width are the actual width and height of the node.

I found this
[Shrinking text to the width of a node within a tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15208/shrinking-text-to-the-width-of-a-node-within-a-tikzpicture),
but I don't want to first generate the node `n` in that example.

I need something like:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 

    \tikzstyle{D}=[shape=diamond, draw, line width=0.2pt, minimum width=0.8cm,   minimum height=0.8cm,inner sep = 0pt]

      \node [D] (m) {\shrinktofitinnode{AAAAAAAA}{??}...{??};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If someone could help me, that would be really good.

Does anyone know a way to calculate the maximal text box that fits into a shape of a certain size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value of the `minimum width` key using `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}` etc. and use it with `\resizebox` (`graphicx` package, already loaded by `tikz`} to resize the content to it. For the `diamond` shape you might want to reduce the width a little more (e.g. to 90%; for tall texts even down to 50%), otherwise the text will touch the lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[D/.style={shape=diamond, draw, line width=0.2pt, minimum width=0.8cm, minimum height=0.8cm,inner sep=0pt}]

 \node [D] (m) {\setkeys{Gin}{keepaspectratio}\resizebox{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}}{AAAAAAAA}};

 \node [D] (k) at (2,0) {\setkeys{Gin}{keepaspectratio}\resizebox{.9\dimexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}\relax}{.9\dimexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}\relax}{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

---

You can also use `adjustbox` for easy further adjustments, e.g. to allow line breaks. The similar TikZ options won't work as normal because `\resizebox` is used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[D/.style={shape=diamond, draw, line width=0.2pt, minimum width=0.8cm, minimum height=0.8cm,inner sep=0pt}]

 \node [D] (m) {\setkeys{Gin}{keepaspectratio}\resizebox{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}}{AAAAAAAA}};

 \node [D] (k) at (2,0) {\adjustbox{varwidth={5cm}\centering,keepaspectratio,width=.9\dimexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}\relax,height=.9\dimexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}\relax}{AAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\BBBBBBBBBBBB\\CCCCCCCCC}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

---

Finally there is the `min size` key of `\adjustbox` which will scale the content down only if required (i.e. it is too large), but keep it the original size otherwise. You might want to define a shortcut macro if you need this more often.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\adjsizetonode}{%
  \adjustbox{varwidth={5cm}\centering,keepaspectratio,max size={.9\dimexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}\relax}{.9\dimexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}\relax}}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[D/.style={shape=diamond, draw, line width=0.2pt, minimum width=0.8cm, minimum height=0.8cm,inner sep=0pt}]

 \node [D] (A)  at (0,0) {a};
 \node [D] (A2) at (1,0) {\adjsizetonode{a}};
 \node [D] (B)  at (2,0) {\adjsizetonode{BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB}};
 \node [D] (B)  at (3,0) {\adjsizetonode{BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB\\bbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbb bbbb bbbb\\Bb bbfd  kslkgldf }};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried the third code and it worked really good except ehen I changed the font size with for example \fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont. Do you have any idea how i can use an arbitrary font size and still get the shapes so nicely adjusted?

Comment: @Jana: A changed font size should not be an issue. Put the font commands either inside the node or use the `font=<..>` TikZ option in the `D/.style` to set the font. AFAIK, TikZ resets the font at the begin of every node, so external font changes won't have an effect.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. One more question: I want to have a little space between the lines of the shape and the text. How do I do that? With the option inner sep = 1pt, the size is getting larger. Thank you so much for your help, I am new to tikz and just starting to find my way around.

Comment: @Jana: The `minimum width` and `minimum height` is for the shape (i.e. the border lines) not the text. So you have to scale to this length minus the space you want. I mentioned that in my answer, i.e. only use `.9` (90%) of the width and height. You can either reduce `.9` to a lower value, e.g. `.8` or subtract a constant value, e.g. `max size={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-1pt}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}-1pt}` should work.