# How to decrease the size of single node in mindmap?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-styles, mindmaps

In `tikz`'s `mindmap`, I want to change the `concept` size for individual parents or children (not the entire system). It is simply possible to increase the size of a child node, by introducing `minimum size` into the `concept` options.

How to decrease the size of a single `concept`, as tikz does not support `maximum size`?

Comment: Possible duplicate? [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15208/](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15208/shrinking-text-to-the-width-of-a-node-within-a-tikzpicture/)

Comment: @CountZero I did not get how to use the Q/A you quoted to solve my problem. I am looking for something like `[concept, minimum size=3cm]` but for maximum. It is not related to the text therein.

Comment: Ok, now I got it.

Comment: What mislead me was the original title with 'font size', but now it makes sense.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can decide to `scale` nodes for example by setting:

```
\tikzset{every node/.append style={scale=0.6}}
```

and then locally redefine the scaling just in the node you are interested in.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\tikzset{level 1 concept/.append style={font=\sf, sibling angle=90,level distance = 25mm}}
\tikzset{level 2 concept/.append style={font=\sf, sibling angle=45,level distance = 15mm}}
\tikzset{level 3 concept/.append style={font=\sf, sibling angle=45,level distance = 15mm}}
\tikzset{every node/.append style={scale=0.6}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, concept color=blue, font=\sf\bf, text=white]
\node[concept]{Root Concept}[clockwise from=315]
                        child[concept color=orange] {node[concept] (c1){Child 1}                                
                                    child [concept color=orange]  {node [concept](c11){Child 1-1}}
                                    child [concept color=orange] {node [concept](c12){Child 1-2}}
                                    child [concept color=orange] {node [concept](c13){Child 1-3}}                                                   
                        }
                        child [concept color=orange] {node [concept](c2){Child 2}
                                    child [concept color=orange] {node [concept,scale=0.4](c21){Child 2-1}}
                                    child [concept color=orange] {node [concept](c22){Child 2-2}}
                                    child [concept color=orange] {node [concept](c22){Child 1-3}}
                        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

will give you:

[image]

Notice the local redefinition in:

```
child [concept color=orange] {node [concept,scale=0.4](c21){Child 2-1}}
```

Comment: Is there any way to change the scale of all the nodes at a given level k? If I add 'scale=0.2' to the level 2 concept style something very bad happens...

Comment: @AntonioSesto: you can try `\tikzset{level 2 concept/.append style={font=\sf, sibling angle=45,level distance = 25mm,scale=0.6,transform shape}}`. Basically the trick is to add `transform shape` for the labels and increase the distance that the scaling option reduces.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to locally change the font size rather than changing the scale

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=3em,text width=3em](a) at (0,0){aaaa};
\begin{scope}\small
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=3em,text width=3em](b) at (4,1){aaaa aaaaa};
\end{scope}
\draw(a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]