# How to adjust font size in TikZ state diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to decrease the font size of nodes to avoid the conflict of this edge penetrating the Node(D)

I just want to decrease the size not anything else,
IN ADDITION, if there is a way to decrease the nodes' radius would be great..

Comment: Can you add the code you have up to now?

Comment: Of course you can always play with the options `scale=<some factor>,transform shape`, but if you just want to reduce the font size you can use the `font` key (i.e. `font=\tiny`). (I'm sure we had recently a question about font size within TikZ, but I didn't find it).

Comment: Well, I just found an answer [HERE][1] 


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58237/how-to-decrease-the-size-of-single-node-in-mindmap