# TikZ: `local bounding box` incompatible with `use as bounding box`?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bounding-box

The TikZ/PGF documentation (v 2.10) contains the following example for the use of `local bounding box`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfmodule{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);
{ [local bounding box=outer box]
    \draw (1,1) circle (.5) [local bounding box=inner box] (2,2) circle (.5);
}
\draw (outer box.south west) rectangle (outer box.north east);
\draw[fill,red] (inner box.south west) rectangle (inner box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

– actually just the `tikzpicture`, I made it into a complete document. This works as advertised until I explicitly set a global bounding box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfmodule{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[use as bounding box] (-1,-1) rectangle (4,3);  % <------------
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);
{ [local bounding box=outer box]
    \draw (1,1) circle (.5) [local bounding box=inner box] (2,2) circle (.5);
}
\draw (outer box.south west) rectangle (outer box.north east);
\draw[fill,red] (inner box.south west) rectangle (inner box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

– then the two drawn outlines of `outer box` and `inner box` disappear. Changing `\draw` to `\fill` indicates that the boxes have become huge and cover the whole page and more.

**My question: How do I get this to work?** Is this a known bug with a workaround?

My goal in using `local bounding box` is to measure the width and height of part of a TikZ figure using [Caramdir's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8761/38399) approach. In case `local bounding box` is broken, what else can I do?

Comment: Try putting `\usetikzlibrary{scopes}` into the preamble.

Comment: That removes the need for an explicit `scope`, but doesn't address my main problem. I'll remove the part about `{}` not working from the question, since apparently the manual example assumed to use this library. Thanks!

Comment: I found a simple workaround: use a clipping path instead of `use as bounding box`. Not the same, but sufficient for my purposes. I'd still like to know why `use as bounding box` interferes with `local bounding box`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of `/tikz/use as bounding box`:

> Normally, when this option is given on a path, the bounding box of the present path is used to determine the size of the picture and **the size of all subsequent paths are ignored**.

This is why you can't use `local bounding box` after it.

But what you can do is to reset the bounding box after that, like this :

```
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path[use as bounding box] (-1,-1) rectangle (4,3);
```

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=10,convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  before
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);
    \scoped[local bounding box=outer box]
      \draw (1,1) circle (.5) [local bounding box=inner box] (2,2) circle (.5);
    \draw (outer box.south west) rectangle (outer box.north east);
    \draw[red] (inner box.south west) rectangle (inner box.north east);
    \pgfresetboundingbox
    \path[use as bounding box] (-1,-1) rectangle (4,3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  after
\end{document}
```

[image]