# Use TikZ matrix inside a savebox: doesn't work because of "&"

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, tikz-matrix

For using a TikZ `matrix` as part of [a nested `tikzpicture`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362328/64454), I define the former in advance and store it in a `savebox`. 
However, when I add a second column, compilation fails. It seems to be due to the `&` (see MWE below). The log notably says: *! Package pgf Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode.*

**Question:** How to define a TikZ `matrix` with multiple columns in a `savebox`?

---

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \newsavebox{\testsbox}
    \savebox{\testsbox}{
        \begin{tikzpicture} [borders/.style={draw, help lines}]
            \matrix[borders]{
                \node [borders] {11};
%           &
%               \node [borders] {12};
            \\
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\begin{document}
    This example stops working as soon as you add a second column (i.e. uncomment lines 9 and 10).
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node {\usebox{\testsbox}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TikZ changes the category code of `&` to be an active character to process the matrix. But the `tikzpicture` is used as argument for `\savebox`. When TeX parses an argument,
then the text is tokenized with the current category code settings. Then, when
TikZ changes the category code, it does not have an effect, because `&` is already tokenized.

LaTeX provides the environment `lrbox` as alternative to the commands `\savebox` or `\sbox`. In the environment form, the contents is not read as argument and
category changes work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox{\testsbox}
\begin{lrbox}{\testsbox}
    \begin{tikzpicture} [borders/.style={draw, help lines}]
        \matrix[borders]{
            \node [borders] {11};
        &
            \node [borders] {12};
        \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node {\usebox{\testsbox}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The environment `lrbox` also removes spaces at the begin and at the end of the body in opposite to `\savebox`/`\sbox`.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `ampersand replacement` to replace `&` by an arbitrary command (most people choose `\&`).

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \newsavebox{\testsbox}
    \savebox{\testsbox}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture} [borders/.style={draw, help lines}]
            \matrix[borders,ampersand replacement=\&]{
                \node [borders] {11};
            \&
                \node [borders] {12};
            \\
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }

\begin{document}
    This example stops working as soon as you add a second column (i.e. uncomment lines 9 and 10).
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node {\usebox{\testsbox}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I should have read the [PGF manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) more carefully, since it is all detailed in *§20.5 Considerations Concerning Active Characters* (v3.0.1a)!

Comment: The spaces by line ends after `\savebox{\testsbox}` and `\end{tikzpicture}` matter and go into the horizontal box `\testsbox`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek nice catch! I should have commented the ends of line.